# PowerShell - Loop Through Nested Objects

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to loop through an organization's PowerBI workspaces and spit out the report IDs, names, and URLs for each workspace - so, a nested loop.

Here's my working script thus far:

```
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

$myArray = @()

Login-PowerBIServiceAccount
Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization | ForEach-Object { 
        $ws = $_
        Get-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $_.Id | ForEach-Object {
            $x = [pscustomobject]@{
                workspaceId = $ws.Id
                workspaceName = $ws.Name
                reportId = $_.id
                reportName = $_.Name
                reportUrl = $_.WebUrl
             }
        $myArray += $x
        }
}

$myArray | Export-Csv "PowerBIWorkspaceReports.csv"
```

Four questions:

1) Is there a better way to add the module dependency at the top? I can't find any info on how PowerBI looks for existing module dependencies.

2) Are the ForEach-Object calls redundant? I see in simple code people assume whatever command runs after the pipe runs just fine whether on a single object or a collection of objects.

3) Is there a better way to manage my objects? Since I need data from the first loop ( the Workspace name and ID) and the second loop, is there an easier way to join them (or export them as a flattened list) than looping?

4) Should I just append my rows directly to the CSV? There doesn't seem to be the equivalent of While(File.Open() ...) in PowerShell.

And any other advice appreciated.

Comment: An other advice (performance related): roll down to _Appending to arrays_ in the [Slow Code: Top 5 Ways to Make Your PowerShell Scripts Run Faster](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/07/12/slow-code-top-5-ways-to-make-your-powershell-scripts-run-faster/) article.  Use `$myArray = Get-PowerBIWorkspace  …` omitting both `$myArray = @()` and `$myArray += ` (and note that you could omit the auxiliary variable `$x` at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rejigged your code a little to make it tidier. I don't have PowerBI, so I haven't tested it, and I can't guarantee that I haven't done anything dumb.

I got rid of the nested loop. Note the `-PipelineVariable ws`. What that does is put the output of that stage of the pipeline into a variable called `$ws`, which we can refer to later. It means that we don't need to do `$ws = $_`.

`-PipelineVariable` is one of the "Common Parameters", and is available on many or most cmdlets. You can abbreviate it to `-PV`, by the way.

I also got rid of the intermediate array `$myArray` since it wasn't needed.

```
Install-Module -Name MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

Login-PowerBIServiceAccount

Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -PipelineVariable ws | 
    ForEach-Object { Get-PowerBIReport -WorkspaceId $_.Id } | 
    ForEach-Object {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                workspaceId   = $ws.Id
                workspaceName = $ws.Name
                reportId      = $_.id
                reportName    = $_.Name
                reportUrl     = $_.WebUrl
             }
        } |
    Export-Csv "PowerBIWorkspaceReports.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for - is there a good tutorial for this sort of PowerShell piping object collections best practices? My Google-fu was a little scattershot.

Comment: @KyleHale there aren't any object collections as such here. It's just single objects moving around.

Comment: Hey @Dangph thanks for the comment, I guess what I mean is, Get-PowerBIWorkspace returns multiple workspace objects. We pipe that to $ws. So how does that $ws also represent the iterated workspace (from ForEach-Object) when we're assigning values from $ws to the custom object? I understand what it's doing, it's just usually in code you have to do that explicitly, so I was wondering what internal mechanim PowerShell has to do that implicitly and if I can learn more about it.

Comment: @KyleHale, you can picture the pipeline as a series of tubes with ping-pong balls (or objects) going through them one at a time. `Get-PowerBIWorkspace` produces ping-pong balls and they go one at a time to the next stage, namely the `ForEach-Object { Get-PowerBIReport ...}`, which will take each ping-pong ball and transform it into a bunch of other objects, golf balls, let's say, which in turn go onto the next stage one at a time.

Comment: [cont.] The `PipelineVariable` just allows downstream stages to look upstream to see what ping-pong ball is currently being processed. Most of the time you won't need `PipelineVariable`, but every so often it will be helpful.